# Java constructor varargs conflict when passing string

Tags: java, constructor, conflict, variadic-functions

I have an issue with one of my class. I'm using a "varargs" constructor for unknown number of parameter.

```
public Groupe(String...nom){        
    for(String item:nom){   
        this.nom.add(item.toLowerCase());
    }
}

public Groupe(String nom){      
    String[] list =nom.split(",");
    for(String s : list){           
        this.nom.add(s.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

The first constructor is called...that's fine, but there is a conflict when passing only ONE parameter with the second contructor. I would like to use the second constructor when passing only one string, and the first if 2 and more parameters.

I'd want to handle this
        new Groupe("Foo,Bar");

This is where I call it. I suspect the "error" comes from there

```
public void reserver(String...nom){
    Groupe gr = new Groupe(nom);
    passager.add(gr);       
}
```

I don't pass a String, but a Varargs (tab?)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be fine, with the caveat that `null` can be converted to either `String[]` or `String`:

```
public class Test {

    public Test(String single) {
        System.out.println("Single");
    }

    public Test(String... multiple) {
        System.out.println("Multiple");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test("Foo"); // Single
        new Test("Foo", "Bar"); // Multiple
        new Test(); // Effectively multiple
        // new Test(null); // Doesn't compile - ambiguous
        new Test((String) null); // Single
    }
}
```

EDIT: Now that you've shown us the calling code, that's definitely the problem:

```
public void reserver(String...nom){
    Groupe gr = new Groupe(nom);
    passager.add(gr);       
}
```

Here, the type of `nom` is `String[]` - so it will always call the first constructor. You've got an array of strings there - under what circumstances do you want to call the second constructor?

To be honest, given that the two constructors act significantly differently, I would actually make both constructors private, and provide static methods:

```
public static Groupe fromStringArray(String... nom)

public static Groupe fromCommaSeparatedString(String nom)
```

Then it will be *absolutely clear* what you're expecting in each case.

Comment: I want to handle this:  new Test("Foo,Bar");

Comment: @user1023021: So what's the problem? That will call the second constructor, which will then split the string on commas.

Comment: The second is never called because "Foo,Bar" is also a String. So the varags constructor is called wich I don't want to.

Comment: @user1023021: No, it's not. Run my sample code! I suspect you've misled yourself with whatever diagnostics you're using. Unfortunately you've not provided enough code for us to see...

Comment: You are right. But how come my single constructor isn't called? I've tried to place it above the multiple. I will edit the OP and add the code where I call it

Comment: @user1023021 Of course its perfect... its Jon Skeet!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can be a solution:

```
public Groupe(String...nom){       
    if (nom.length == 1) {
        add(nom[0].split(","));
    } else {
        add(nom);
    }
}

private void add(String[] list) {
    for(String s : list){           
        this.nom.add(s.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: For now, I am using a similar solution. Thanks tulio

Answer (score 2):

The varargs part can be empty. So you can get what you want with

```
public Groupe(String nom){
  String[] list = nom.split(",");
for(String s : list){           
    this.nom.add(s.toLowerCase());
}

 public Groupe(String nom1, String nom2, String...nom){   
this.nom.add(nom1);
this.nom.add(nom2);     
for(String item:nom)    
    this.nom.add(item.toLowerCase());
}
```

You could also, of course, use one ctor with an if statement on the length of the input array, splitting out cases 0 (not handled with the code above), 1, and > 1.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class OverloadVarArgs {

public static void main(String... args){
    OverloadVarArgs a = new OverloadVarArgs("One Argument");
    OverloadVarArgs b = new OverloadVarArgs("Two", "Arguments");
    OverloadVarArgs c = new OverloadVarArgs("One, Argument");

}

public OverloadVarArgs(String a){
    System.out.println("Constructor 1");
}

public OverloadVarArgs(String... a){
    System.out.println("Constructor 2");
}
}
```

Output:

Constructor 1

Constructor 2

Constructor 1

Comment: I've tried it ...with a single parameters, the varargs constructor is called  and not the single parameter constructor.

Comment: Ordering of the ctors in Java is irrelevant.